# making a map in which the value type is an abstract class

Tags: java, generics

How can i store a FieldMember type into this SortedMap? My goal is to send 0 as that type.

```
public class Polynom<E> implements IPolynom<E>{

    private SortedMap<Integer, FieldMember<E>> coefficients;

    /**
     * constructor: create the zero polynomial.
     */
    public Polynom() {
           FieldMember<E> fm = new FieldMemberImpl(0);
        coefficients.put(1,(FieldMember<E>) fm.getValue());
    }
```

Here's a snippet of the abstract class if it helps:

```
public abstract class FieldMember<E> {

    private E value;

    public FieldMember(E value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: You have made the FieldMember class abstract when it doesn't need to be because you have implementations for two of the methods. Why not simply remove the abstract keyword, create an instance of it: FieldMember<Integer> i = new FieldMember<>(1) and store it in the map?

Comment: @M.Gianota I cant change anything, the class was given to us like that and im supposed to solve it without altering anything.

Comment: Oh, I see. You simply need to create a concrete implementation of FieldMember by creating a new class that extends FieldMember. Then, create an instance of your new class and add it to the map.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to create a concrete implementation of FieldMember by creating a new class that extends FieldMember. Then, create an instance of your new class and add it to the map.

The following code will create a concrete implementation of the FieldMember abstract class. In the code, I just print out its value, but you will want to add it to the map.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FieldMember<Integer> fm = new FieldMemberImpl(0);
        System.out.println(fm.getValue());
    }

    static class FieldMemberImpl<E> extends FieldMember {
        public FieldMemberImpl(E value) {
            super(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cant make it work, having a casting error. edited the post for the changes i made

Comment: @noor You want to say this: `coefficients.put(1,fm);` instead. :) Put a reference to the FieldMember class in the map. You were trying to cast an Integer to a FieldMember type which is why you got the ClassCastException.

Comment: i just cant make it work, and im getting really tired of Java and oop recently. now im getting this error "Cannot invoke "java.util.SortedMap.put(Object, Object)" because "this.coefficients" is null". I changed that line as u said, am i missing something else?

Comment: Try not to get dispirited. The error is simple. You have not created an instance of the SortedMap so you are getting a null pointer. Add the following line just above the `SortedMap.put()` line: `coefficients = new SortedMap<>();`